# Does it sound strange to write "plant's water and nutrients intake"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, collocation

there. I'd like to know if "intake" can be used with "plant" in "plant's water and nutrients intake". Or does it sound strange? Thanks.

Comment: Generally it would be written "plant's water and nutrient intake".  "Nutrient", in this sense, is a sort of mass noun and isn't pluralized.

Comment: If *plant's water intake* and *plant's nutrient intake* (echoing the previous comment that you probably want that to be singular) both make sense on their own, then *plant's **water and nutrient** intake* follows a common convention of collapsing the two things.

Comment: I have a bit of an aversion to using nouns as adjectives, but that's just me. So, in this case, I would go with "plant's intake of water and nutrients*. You then wouldn't have to worry about whether to use *nutrient* or *nutrients*. Also, I'm not sure there's anything technically wrong with *nutrients intake* other than it seems a little strange.

Comment: Hey guys! thank you all. You helped me a lot! Richard Kayser, I think I will accept your suggestion.